# Restar fechas como string en PHP (Orientación a Objetos)

Tags: php, date

Partiendo de una **clase Alumno**, con un método **soy_mayor_de_edad()** que nos **devuelve un booleano**, necesito restar dos fechas (strings) cuyo formato es el siguiente "Y-m-d" (Es decir, un ejemplo "2019-04-27").

Las fechas que necesito restar es el año del nacimiento del alumno, en el mismo formato. Con la fecha actual (Tambien en el mismo formato).

Partiendo de una prueba simple en un **index.php** en Apache, realicé lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

$fechaNacimiento="1993-03-30";
$fechaActual=date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");

$resultado = $fechaActual-$fechaNacimiento;

//El resultado es "26 años".
echo($resultado." años");

?>
```

Pero en el programa que intenté implementar lo anterior, me daba un error en los tests al intentar restar fechas de esa forma. Para ello, conseguí hacerlo sin errores de la siguiente manera (Funciona):

```php
public function soy_mayor_de_edad(): bool{

         //Obtengo la fecha del propio alumno.
         //Es un string "Y-m-d" resultado de una consulta a una base de datos.
         $fechaNacimiento=$this->nacimiento;

         //Convierto la fecha a un string sin los guiones.              
         $fechaNacimientoInt=$fechaNacimiento[0].$fechaNacimiento[1].$fechaNacimiento[2].$fechaNacimiento[3].$fechaNacimiento[5].$fechaNacimiento[6].$fechaNacimiento[8].$fechaNacimiento[9];

         //Convierto la fecha a un entero para poder restarla.
         $fechaNacimientoInt=(int)$fechaNacimientoInt;


         //Hago lo mismo con la fecha actual.
         $fechaActual=(date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d"));
         $fechaActualInt=$fechaActual[0].$fechaActual[1].$fechaActual[2].$fechaActual[3].$fechaActual[5].$fechaActual[6].$fechaActual[8].$fechaActual[9];
         $fechaActualInt=(int)$fechaActualInt;

         //El resultado (la resta) es un numero entero, 
         //cuyos dos numeros principales serán los años.
         $resultado=$fechaActualInt-$fechaNacimientoInt;

        //En el siguiente numero hay un pequeño problema. 
        //Si es un numero de 6 digitos,  
        //los dos primeros numeros son los años que tiene,
        // pero si es de 5 digitos, solo es el primero numero.

        $resultado=(string)$resultado;
        //Por lo tanto tengo que contar los digitos que tiene el numero, y dependiendo de si son 5 o 6, debo obtener los dos primeros o el primer numero
        if(strlen($resultado)==6){
                $resultadoInt=$resultado[0].$resultado[1];
                $resultadoInt=(int)$resultadoInt;
        }else{
                $resultadoInt=$resultado[0];
                $resultadoInt=(int)$resultadoInt;
        }

        //Si el resultado es menor a 18, es menor, si no, es mayor de edad.
        if($resultadoInt<18){
                return False;
        }else{
                return True;
        }
}
```

Me gustaría saber si se puede conseguir de una forma más simple y limpia, sin la necesidad de tanto código ni de realizar tantas operaciones. Teniendo en cuenta que la **fecha de nacimiento del alumno, es un string en formato "Y-m-d"** ya que es el resultado de una consulta a una base de datos.

Comment: Conviertelas a tipo date asi facilitas los calculos.

Comment: Prueba esto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-create-from-format.php

Comment: Dado que es una clase `Alumno`, ¿la misma no tiene un método para obtener la edad del alumno? De ser así, el método se escribiría así más o menos: `public function isMajor() { return $this->getAge() < 18; }`, pues la edad se estaría calculando en `getAge()`. Me parece que la edad se usará muchas veces en el contexto de la clase ¿no?

Comment: No existe dicho método, ya que no existe el atributo edad en la clase. Existe solo el atributo de la fecha de nacimiento. La clase es una implementación de una interfaz, para un programa que instancia los alumnos de una base de datos en la cual no existe dicho atributo edad. Es un ejercicio para la utilización de base de datos desde PHP con orientación a objetos. Por eso la necesidad de calcular la edad de dicha manera, ya que el resultado debe ser validado por una serie de tests.

Comment: No tiene por qué existir un atributo edad o un campo edad en la BD, ya que es un campo calculado. Pero si por ejemplo se requiriesen informes o estadísticas basadas en la edad del alumno, convendría tener un método que la calcule y en ese caso, el método que verifica si es mayor de edad se auxiliaría del método que calcula la edad propiamente, de ese modo evitarías código redundante. Pero si dices que la edad nunca se usa, OK.

Comment: Es más simple de lo que parece, así es, no se utiliza la edad para nada, simplemente se necesita el método **soy_mayor_de_edad()** para cumplir los tests. No se necesita la edad para nada, aunque tiene sentido lo del método método **getAge()** y es una información muy útil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una manera en la que puedes hacerlo es de la siguiente:

Cogemos la fecha de nacimiento:

```
$nacimiento= new DateTime("1993-03-30);
```

Ahora la fecha actual:

```
$hoy = new DateTime();
```

Con la función [diff](https://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) de PHP calculamos la edad:

```
$anios= $hoy->diff($nacimiento);
```

El resultado de esto:

```
echo $anios->y; //26 años
```

Ejemplo completo podría ser así:

```
public function soy_mayor_de_edad(): bool{

    $nacimiento= new DateTime("1993-03-30");
    $hoy = new DateTime();
    $anios= $hoy->diff($nacimiento);

    return $anios->y < 18; //Devolverá al método true o false
}
```

Comment: Dado que quiere ahorrar código, según dice, te puedes quitar 4 líneas de encima cambiando todo el bloque `if` por simplemente esto: **`return $anios->y < 18;`** Y el método devolverá `TRUE` o `FALSE` según la condición se cumpla o no.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón, ahora mismo edito, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Una forma más simple es convirtiendo las fechas **string** a objetos DateTime, calculando la diferencia que hay entre esas fechas:

```php
public function soy_mayor_de_edad(): bool{
         //Obtengo la fecha del propio alumno.
         $fechaNacimiento=$this->nacimiento;
         $fechaActual=date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");

         //Convierto ambas fechas en un objeto DateTime.
         $fechaNacimiento=date_create($fechaNacimiento);
         $fechaActual=date_create($fechaActual);

         //Comparo la diferencia que hay entre ambas fechas
         $resultado=$fechaActual->diff($fechaNacimiento);
         //obtengo los años de diferencia
         $resultado=$resultado->y;

        //Si el resultado es menor a 18, es menor, si no, es mayor de edad.
        if($resultado<18){
                return False;
        }else{
                return True;
        }
}
```